# Intersection of 3 planes with cgal

Tags: c++, boost, cgal

I am coding to get point intersection of 3 planes with cgal.

Then I have this code.

```
Plane_3 suelo(Point_3(0,0,0), Vector_3(0,0,-1));    
Plane_3 principal( Point_3(0,0,0),Vector_3(0,1,0)); 
Plane_3 lateral3(Point_3(0,5,0),Vector_3(-1,0,0));  
boost::optional<boost::variant<Point_3, Line_3, Plane_3>> res = CGAL::intersection(suelo, principal, lateral3);

if (res!=boost::none)
{
    qDebug(" TRACKING 001 ");
    qDebug("\n");
    if (const Plane_3* pl = boost::get<Plane_3>(&(*res)))
    {
        qDebug(" TRACKING 002 ");
        qDebug("\n");
    }
    else if ( const Line_3* l = boost::get<Line_3>(&(*res)))
    {
        assert(l!=NULL);
        qDebug(" TRACKING 003 ");
        qDebug("\n");
    }
    else if ( const Point_3* p = boost::get<Point_3>(&(*res)))
    {
        qDebug(" TRACKING 004");
        std::cout<<"el punto es:"<<p<<std::endl;
        qDebug(" TRACKING 005");
        K_01::RT y = p->y();
        std::cout<<"el punto y es:"<<p->y()<<std::endl;
        qDebug(" TRACKING 006");
        std::cout<<"el punto x es:"<<p->x()<<std::endl;
        qDebug(" TRACKING 007");
    }
}
```

I calculate it manually and I know that result is this a point (0,0,0)

I think this is the good way but when I try to access to value x,y,z of this calculated point it hasn't anything.

Could anyone help me to find the mistake?

On the other hand,
I want to calculate all point intersections of all planes and store them in some structure.

Could someone tell me, what is the best way to do that?
In my case I want to store all points intersections that are part of a cube.

I read all planes of this cube and generate all points of this cube.

Could you help me?